# Reformatting of JS Object to obtain Year/Month/Week total

Tags: javascript

I have data as follows:

```
{
   "2011":{
      "01":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2011-01-01"
            },
            {
               "date":"2011-01-02"
            }
         ]
      },
      "02":{
         "01":[
            {
              
               "date":"2011-02-02"
            }
         ],
         "03":[
            {
               "date":"2011-02-15"
            },
            {                  
               "date":"2011-02-17"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "2012":{
      "01":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2012-01-01"
            }
         ]
      },
      "03":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2012-03-03"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I need to construct final data in the below format:

```
[{year:2011,month:'Jan',week_no:1, week_total:2},
{year:2011,month:'Jan',week_no:2, week_total:2},
{year:2012,month:'Jan',week_no:1, week_total:1}
{year:2012,month:'Mar',week_no:1, week_total:1}]
```

Purpose is to obtain  Year/Month / Week-wise totals.
This data is required to plot some charts later.
Help on this is highly appreciated..!..

Thanks in advance
ASJ

Answer (score 1):

Try this (details in the inline comments):

```
// Your data
const data = {
   "2011":{
      "01":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2011-01-01"
            },
            {
               "date":"2011-01-02"
            }
         ]
      },
      "02":{
         "01":[
            {
              
               "date":"2011-02-02"
            }
         ],
         "03":[
            {
               "date":"2011-02-15"
            },
            {                  
               "date":"2011-02-17"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "2012":{
      "01":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2012-01-01"
            }
         ]
      },
      "03":{
         "01":[
            {
               "date":"2012-03-03"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
};

// Helper for month codes
const monthCodes = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

// Init empty plot data object
let plotData = [];

// Loop year input data object
for (const [yearKey, yearValue] of Object.entries(data)) {

  // Loop month input data object
  for (const [monthKey, monthValue] of Object.entries(yearValue)) {
    const weeksInMonth = Object.entries(monthValue);
    
    // Loopp week input data
    for (const [weekKey, weekValue] of weeksInMonth) {
        // Create new data item for year and month
        const dataItem = { 
            year: parseInt(yearKey),
            month: monthCodes[parseInt(monthKey) - 1],
            week_no: parseInt(weekKey),
            week_total: weekValue.length
        };
      
        // Insert to plot data item
        plotData.push(dataItem);
    }
  }
}

console.log(plotData);
```

I think in your output should be 5 items instead 4. For each existing week 1 item. Output:

```
[
    { month: "Jan", week_no: 1, week_total: 2, year: 2011 },
    { month: "Feb", week_no: 1, week_total: 1, year: 2011 },
    { month: "Feb", week_no: 3, week_total: 2, year: 2011 },
    { month: "Jan", week_no: 1, week_total: 1, year: 2012 },
    { month: "Mar", week_no: 1, week_total: 1, year: 2012 }
]
```

Comment: This one is definitely the most correct and most readable one. I considered using `Array.prototype.flatMap()` but it seems like using nested for loops is simply more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the data by looping through each year, month, and week.
Then constructing an object based on the information we have created.

> Assumes `ogData` is the data you wish to convert

```js
var years = Object.keys(ogData);
var newData = [];

for (var i=0; i<years.length; i++) {console.log("1")
    var year = years[i];
    var months = Object.keys(ogData[year]);
    for (var i2=0; i2<months.length; i2++) {console.log("2")
        var month = months[i2];
        var weeks = Object.keys(ogData[year][month]);
        for (var i3=0; i3<weeks.length; i3++) {console.log("3")
            var week = weeks[i3];
            newData.push({
                year: year,
                month: toName(month),
                week_no: week,
                week_total: ogData[year][month][week].length
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now we just need to convert the month from a number, to a name.

```
var all_months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
]
function toName(num) {
    // `parseInt` accepts `"01"` as `1`
    num = parseInt(num);
    // `-1` to start index at 0
    return all_months[num-1];
}
```

The above code together outputs the following for your dataset

```json
[{"year":"2011","month":"Jan","week_no":"01","week_total":2},
{"year":"2011","month":"Feb","week_no":"01","week_total":1},
{"year":"2011","month":"Feb","week_no":"03","week_total":2},
{"year":"2012","month":"Jan","week_no":"01","week_total":1},
{"year":"2012","month":"Mar","week_no":"01","week_total":1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(`{
    "2011": {
        "01": {
            "01": [{
                    "date": "2011-01-01"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2011-01-02"
                }
            ]
        },
        "02": {
            "01": [{

                "date": "2011-02-02"
            }],
            "03": [{
                    "date": "2011-02-15"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2011-02-17"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "2012": {
        "01": {
            "01": [{
                "date": "2012-01-01"
            }]
        },
        "03": {
            "01": [{
                "date": "2012-03-03"
            }]
        }
    }
}`);
var output = [];
    var months =  ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    for (var key in obj) {
        for(var _k in obj[key]){
            var _int = obj[key][_k];
            for(var _w in _int){
                output.push({year: parseInt(key), month: months[parseInt(_k)-1], week_no: parseInt(_w), week_total: _int[_w].length});
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(output);
```